# ps2exe resulting file gives illegal character in path but runs fine as a ps1 file

Tags: powershell, ps2exe-gui

I have a pretty extensive Powershell script that I'm working on that generates a GUI interface and gives access to a lot of different functions. Stand alone, the Powershell script runs fine when executed as a Powershell script. When I use the PS2EXE tool and convert it to an executable and then try to run the exe, it comes up with an error message saying illegal character in file path and then continues to show dialogue saying cannot find Drive. A drive with a name.... And then it shows me the first couple lines of my commented section at the beginning of the Powershell script. Even if I remove this commented section it still does the same thing, just shows the first several lines of my script. Not exactly sure what's going on. My Powershell script relies on getting the current directory as I run the script from a thumb drive. So I've tried a couple different ways of getting the current directory, as I understand that sometimes converting to an executable has issues with this.

```
# Get the current script or exe's directory
$currentDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName([System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

or

```
# Get the current script or exe's directory
$currentDir = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
```

this variable is referenced several times later on when populating some text box with contents of directories and building a tools menu that auto-populates with another directory structure.

```
    Line  20: $currentDir = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Line 208: $scriptPath = Join-Path -Path $currentDir -ChildPath "scripts"
Line 223: $softwarePath = Join-Path -Path $currentDir -ChildPath "software"
Line 229: $webShortcutsPath = Join-Path -Path $currentDir -ChildPath "WebShortcuts"
Line 466: $formtoolsPath = Join-Path -Path $currentDir -ChildPath "formtools"
```

My guess is that it has something to do with the fact that when I convert it to an exe it does not like how I'm getting the current script or exe directory. I have other Powershell scripts that run just fine when I convert them to an exe but they're not getting any kind of a current running directory.

I guess just let me know what you'd like to see, I can post my entire code here, but it is pretty extensive. Currently almost 700 lines.

I've tried a couple different ways of getting the current directory to see which one would work best.

```
# Get the current script or exe's directory
$currentDir = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName([System.Reflection.Assembly]::GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

or

```
[# Get the current script or exe's directory
$currentDir = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition][1]
```

Comment: This may not necessarily have to do with how I am getting the current relative directory to the script, but how it's being used later on in the script. It may be that after it's converted to an exe it doesn't like how the file paths are being formatted. I'm looking into it but any feedback would be great.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the line that actually causes the error. Generally, the `Illegal characters in path` error indicates that one of the following characters is present in a path / file name: `* ? " < > |`

Comment: Please bear with me as this is my first post on stack Overflow. So to clarify I don't get any error messages when I run the Powershell script natively. It's when I convert it to an executable that it comes up with an error message in a dialog box. I have attached a screenshot of the error message that it pops up two or three times before finally continuing to the program itself. But then nothing is populated in the fields that require knowing which directory the resources are in. So it's not giving me anything to indicate what character is wrong.

Comment: I've added some information regarding the four other locations in the script where I am forming paths based on the $currentDir variable. It is my belief that after converting the Powershell to an executable that it is having difficulty with these lines and being able to form the full path. I need the path to be relative as the script may change locations in a file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an explanation for your specific symptom, but I expect the problem to go away if you switch to the following method for determining your script's / executable's own directory:

```bash
$ownDir = 
  if ($PSScriptRoot) { # running as .ps1 script
    $PSScriptRoot 
  } else {             # running as .exe 
    Split-Path -Parent (Convert-Path -LiteralPath ([System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs()[0]))
  }
```

Neither of your attempts to determine this directory works from a [`ps2exe`](https://github.com/MScholtes/PS2EXE)-compiled executable.

- The [automatic `$PSScriptRoot` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psscriptroot) variable as well as [`$PSCommandPath`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#pscommandpath) are only defined inside `*.ps1` scripts and `*.psm1` modules.
- `ps2exe` (`Invoke-ps2exe`) embeds the *contents* of the input script *inside the executable* that it creates, which is why those variables do *not* work there.

  - However, you can determine the full path of the *executable* via [`[System.Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs())`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetCommandLineArgs)`[0]`, which contains the executable path *as invoked* (when calling from `cmd.exe`) or *in full* (when calling from PowerShell).
  - So as to ensure that its *full* path is always used, the result is passed to [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path).

Comment: You're a rockstar. That was it. That works flawlessly. And I want to make sure everybody has a link for this. I'm putting this script along with a couple others up on GitHub. I run my own Managed IT business and a tool like this is something I've always wanted. So I finally started putting it together.
https://github.com/Xerophayze/TEKMaster/tree/main

Comment: Glad to hear it, @user22828697.